# Python_Cumulative sum based on two conditions

Tags: python, sum, cumulative-sum, binning

I'm trying to compute the **cumulative sum** in python based on a two different conditions.

As you can see in the attached image, `Calculation` column would take the same value as the `Number` column as long as the `Cat1` and `Cat2` column doesn't change.

Once `Cat1` column changes, we should reset the `Number` column.

`Calculation` column stays the same as the `Number` column, Once `Cat2` column changes with the same value of `Cat1` column, the `Calculation` column will take the last value of the `Number` column and add it to the next one.

---

Example of data below:

```
Cat1    Cat2    Number  CALCULATION
a   orange  1   1
a   orange  2   2
a   orange  3   3
a   orange  4   4
a   orange  5   5
a   orange  6   6
a   orange  7   7
a   orange  8   8
a   orange  9   9
a   orange  10  10
a   orange  11  11
a   orange  12  12
a   orange  13  13
b   purple  1   1
b   purple  2   2
b   purple  3   3
b   purple  4   4
b   purple  5   5
b   purple  6   6
b   purple  7   7
b   purple  8   8
b   silver  1   9
b   silver  2   10
b   silver  3   11
b   silver  4   12
b   silver  5   13
b   silver  6   14
b   silver  7   15
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide a reproducible example so we can copy-paste it. Are you using pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cat1': ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',  'a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
 'Cat2': ['orange','orange','orange','orange','orange','orange','orange',  'orange','orange','orange','orange','orange','orange','purple','purple',  'purple','purple','purple','purple','purple','purple','silver','silver','silver',  'silver','silver','silver','silver']})

df['Number'] = df.groupby(['Cat1', 'Cat2']).cumcount()+1
df['CALCULATION'] = df.groupby('Cat1').cumcount()+1
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your solution. However, maybe it was a bad Example putting the "Number" column to increase by one all the time, but this is not the case. It is always increasing but not necessarily by one.